# Completely disable desktop Notes (KDE Plasma 5)

Tags: kde, kde-plasma-5

I'm running Fedora24/KDE5. Every time I accidentally middle click the desktop or drag a file/tab from a text editor onto it I get a "Note" stuck on the desktop.

[image]

I can remove it by right clicking the bottom part and choosing "Remove Note". I can disable the middle mouse action in desktop settings (from right click menu). I can't stop them appearing when dragging files (just noticed when dragging a tab from my text editor). I want them completely gone. Is there a package I can uninstall or some option to turn them off?

Answer (score 20):

- Right-click on the desktop
- 'Configure Desktop'
- 'Mouse Actions'
- To the right of the button that says 'Middle-Button' there's a button that says 'Paste' and then some more buttons.
- Click on the rightmost button that looks like a minus sign,
- then click on 'OK' or 'Apply'.

Comment: Thank you! It is more than a little infuriating that I cannot find these mouse actions through search or through the system settings - terrible discoverability.

Answer (score 10):

You can remove individual notes by right clicking on the (almost invisible) border around the note and selecting "remove this note"

[image: Right Click Menu]

Comment: No, you can't. No amount of clicking (left or right) gives me any such option.

Comment: It worked for me.

Comment: @Auspex I had the same issue, a long clock in the border area did the trick for me.

Comment: this is the correct way of removing those notes that "appeared out of nowhere on the desktop" and it seems cannot be removed.
KDE should REALLY have a X to wack them.

Comment: Abysmal UX - really hope they fix this

Comment: Add a few more newlines until the scrollbar appears.  Then right click on the scrollbar to remove.   Absolutely awful UX.